# Yii 1.x - required field saves empty

Tags: php, forms, required, is-empty, yii1.x

I have a field set as required in the model, yet I have seen users saving it as an empty string (ie. `''`). When I tested it, I do receive the "Cannot be blank" message properly, so don't know how to prevent this in the future. Do I have to specify all scenarios in the rule (eg, 'insert', 'update')? By the way, I tried updating the field, and it doesn't let me save it empty (I even tries spaces).

These are the rules applied on the field (model):

```php
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('field', 'required'),
        array('field', 'length', 'max'=>4096),
        array('field', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

For @RiggsFolly :) the controller action:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = Model::model()->findByPk($id);

    $formData = Yii::app()->request->getPost('Model'); 

    if ($formData)
    {

        $model->attributes = $formData;
        $model->save(); 
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model
     ));
}
```

... and the view:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'form'
)); ?>

<?php echo $form->textArea($model,'text',array( 'rows'=>5 ')); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Can you imagine any scenario this field could be saving an empty string in the database?

Comment: Do you actually use this rules method anywhere. On its own its just noise

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't understand your question...

Comment: The code you show does not do anything unless it is called somewhere!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Seriously? This is not some basic error like I can't put a model, a controller and a view together, it's a strange exception, and I'm looking for ideas to test, not a correction of a dot or a comma somewhere. But so your apparent perfectionism is satisfied, let me add a brief of the controller and view...

Comment: @RiggsFolly done... better?

Comment: I admit I am no YII Expert, but dont you have to call `$model->validate()` somewhere to get the validation to actually execute?

Comment: @RiggsFolly not needed, only if you need a JSON response of the error messages ([see details here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#validate-detail))

Comment: @webeno have you tried with validate?

Comment: @MackProgramsAlot Have I tried what with validate? the validations works just fine, it does give me the error message, here I'm asking about exceptions, whatever a user can possibly dp to get through the `required` validation and post a form field totally empty - I don't understand how some of these turn up in my db

Comment: @webeno I see what you're saying. Very odd. Have you checked all areas of source code (outside of what we see above) that use this model? Does the column have a default value?

Comment: @MackProgramsAlot I'd have to look through several places, but I hoped there was something easy Inmay have missed, like forcing allowEmpty to be false, but I understand that's not needed if the field is required... the columns has default value null, but even setting that to not null would allow to save empty values (tested that)

Comment: I would right click --> find usages on the Model's Class Name, then find anywhere i see ->save() being called.... 

Sorry I couldn't be of any extra help. Update me if you figure out.

Comment: @MackProgramsAlot Thanks, will give it a try